# In JPA OneToMany relationship, when are entities instantiated?

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

If I have an Account with many Positions I think when I save the Account the Positions are automatically saved also. However, when I want later to start up the application and bring into memory the Accounts, will the complementary action occur -- that is, will the Positions also automatically be brought into memory?

By the way, I notice by using the debugger that the positionList is not a simple List but instead is something called an IndirectList -- is it important to understand the details of this?

Comment: The default fetching strategy for `one-to-many` association is `LAZY`. that means the associated collections would not be brought into memory until they are accessed.

Comment: Thanks Naresh. Ideally. I would like to read in all the Accounts which would cause the Positions to be instantiated also. Can this be done by specifying the opposite of Lazy? But even with Lazy, since the list of Positions is referred to by Account, what happens when you refer to Positions -- is the list Null? If not, how does this work?

Comment: Yes. By specifying the opposite of LAZY (i.e EAGER), the associated collections would also be instantiated. If you use LAZY and try to access the list, the framework would try to fetch the lists. List would not be null.

Comment: If you use LAZY, the entities will be instantiated but fetching the data from database will postpone to when you call the attributes of entity. So you never get null if there is correspinding data in db.